# Is proportionality in log space valid? (Example: Bayes Theorem)

Tags: probability, logarithms, bayes-theorem

For Bayes we can write

$$
p(X|Y) = \frac{p(X)\ p(Y|X)}{p(Y)} \propto p(X)\ p(Y|X)
$$

in log space we can use the sum, for example when we want to calculate the maximum.

$$
argmax_k\ p(X=k|Y) = argmax_k\ \log p(X=k) + \log p(Y|X=k)
$$

---

### Question

Is there a way to formulate proportionality in log space as well?
Writing:

$$
[\log] \ \ p(X=k|Y) \propto \log p(X=k) + \log p(Y|X=k)
$$

feels wrong with and without logarithm on the left side.

Comment: Proportionality involves an unspecified constant factor.  When you take logs, that becomes an unspecified **additive** constant term. So you no longer have proportionality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that was my thought as well. Still wondering if it could still be symbolized somehow